# If A⊂B, And A is a subspace of B, then is A closed as a subspace of X?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of $X$.

If $A\subset B$, And $A$ is a subspace of $B$, then is $A$ closed as a subspace of $X$?
I was thinking it is. I can' think of a counterexample.

Comment: Well, I think you need to tell us a little more about your question. Are you asking about metric spaces? Topological spaces in general? What do we already know about A and B? Are these just arbitrary subsets of X?

Comment: I have edited it now, thanks for the valid input.

Comment: I doubt you formulated your question correctly, however take any non-closed subset $A$ and let $B:=A$.

Comment: you probably meant $A \subset B$ is closed. In this case, the answer is still know. Again, you can take any non-closed subset $B$ and take $A=B$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $B=X$, and $A$ is an non-closed subset of $X$, then that's a quick counterexample, but that's kind of cheap, so I assume you're looking for non-trivial counterexamples.

Let $(X,\tau)$ be given, with $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $\tau=\{X,\emptyset,A,B\}$, with $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{a,b\}$. Then $A\subset B$, $A$ is a subspace of $B$, and $X\backslash A\notin\tau$, so $A$ is not closed in $(X,\tau)$, which means $A$ is not a closed subspace of $X$.

However, there may be other conditions you could add to your original statement to make it true. It looks like you've got a bit of studying to do.